# Dynamic multi header column in Kendo MVC grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to create a grid from the following model.

```
public class ProgramBreakdown
{
    public string ProgramName{ get; set; }
    public List<MonthwiseInfo> MonthwiseProgramInfo { get; set; }
}

public class MonthwiseInfo
{
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public int TotalUsers { get; set; }
    public int ActiveUsers { get; set; }
    public double ActivePerc{ get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to dynamically add/define multi-header columns like shown in the image in Kendo MVC - server side or client side?

Comment: did you figure out how to accomplish this? I need this also.